# Bootstrap confirm-modal doesn't work when link is injected in <tbody>

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have a mysql table with some customers and I have Jquery (live)search to search through the that table. When a customer is found you can delete or edit it as you can see below:

[image]

But when I click on the delete button, I want to get a confirm dialog.
I found this piece of code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[data-confirm]').click(function(ev) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        if (!$('#dataConfirmModal').length) {
            $('body').append('<div id="dataConfirmModal" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dataConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><h3 id="dataConfirmLabel">Confirm</h3></div><div class="modal-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"><a class="btn btn-danger" id="dataConfirmOK">Yes</a><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">No</button></div></div>');
        } 
        $('#dataConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('data-confirm'));
        $('#dataConfirmOK').attr('href', href);
        $('#dataConfirmModal').modal({show:true});
        return false;
    });
});
```

And the modal looks like this:

[image]

This works perfect when I just do:

```
<a href="#" data-confirm="Are you sure?">Delete</a>
```

Now the thing is: the search results are injected in the html table like this:

```
<tbody id="customers"></tbody>
```

I pull the data from the mysql table like this:

```
     while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $fetch ) ) {
        $sResults .= '<tr id="'. $row->customer_id . '">';
        $sResults .= '<td>' . $row->klantcode . '</td>';
        $sResults .= '<td>' . $row->naam . '</td>';
        $sResults .= '<td>' . $row->adres . '</td>';
        $sResults .= '<td>' . $row->plaats . '</td>';
        $sResults .= '<td><a href=index.php?actie=klantbewerken&klant=' . $row->klantcode . '><img class="del" src="../includes/img/edit.png"/></td>';
        $sResults .= '<td><a href=index.php?actie=verwijderen&klant=' . $row->klantcode . ' data-confirm="Are you sure?"><img class="del" src="../includes/img/delete.png"/></td>';
        $sResults .= '</tr>';
    } 

}
echo $sResults;
```

And the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#customers').html('<p>Search for a customer.</p>');
    $('#customersearch').keyup(function() {
        var searchVal = $(this).val();

        if(searchVal !== '') {
       $.get('../administration/page/customers/customersearch.php?klant='+searchVal, function(returnData) {

                if (!returnData) {
                    $('#customers').html('<p>No customers found.</p>');
                } else {
                    $('#customers').html(returnData);                        
                }  

            });
        } else {
            $('#customers').html('<p>Search...</p>');
        }
    });
});
```

So the question is: Why can I get the confirm modal when I do like this:

```
<a href="#" data-confirm="Are you sure?">Delete</a>
```

and why it doesn't work when the `data-confirm` attribute is injected with the search results like:

```
$sResults .= '<td><a href=index.php?actie=verwijderen&klant=' . $row->klantcode . ' data-confirm="Are you sure?"><img class="del" src="../includes/img/delete.png"/></td>';
```

Comment: Because those links did not exist in the DOM when your script assigned click handlers … use `.on` in the way that emulates `.live` instead of `.click`

Comment: I tried:  $('a[data-confirm]').on('click', function(ev) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href'); But that makes no difference.. Can you please help me a little more? @CBroe

Comment: That is not the on syntax that is equivalent to .live – the jQuery docs have more info.

Comment: Thank you for pushing me in the right direction @CBroe! The problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

**OLD CODE:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[data-confirm]').click(function(ev) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        if (!$('#dataConfirmModal').length) {
            $('body').append('<div id="dataConfirmModal" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dataConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><h3 id="dataConfirmLabel">Confirm</h3></div><div class="modal-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"><a class="btn btn-danger" id="dataConfirmOK">Yes</a><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">No</button></div></div>');
        } 
        $('#dataConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('data-confirm'));
        $('#dataConfirmOK').attr('href', href);
        $('#dataConfirmModal').modal({show:true});
        return false;
    });
});
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', 'a[data-confirm]', function(ev) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        if (!$('#dataConfirmModal').length) {
            $('body').append('<div id="dataConfirmModal" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dataConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><h3 id="dataConfirmLabel">Confirm</h3></div><div class="modal-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"><a class="btn btn-danger" id="dataConfirmOK">Yes</a><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">No</button></div></div>');
        } 
        $('#dataConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('data-confirm'));
        $('#dataConfirmOK').attr('href', href);
        $('#dataConfirmModal').modal({show:true});
        return false;
    });
});
```